# How do you take output from print() and put it into a set of variables, one in each?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables, while-loop

I want to save the output of the line *`print(LettersUpC[CodeNum])`* into a variable *outside*, but have it be a different variable each time. How can I accomplish this?

```py
    while 1 == 1:
        CodeWord = str(input("Code-word: "))
        Stop = ["Stop", "Exit", "End", "Terminate"]
        if CodeWord in Stop:
            exit("User Terminate")
        while CodeNum < 55:
            if CodeWord == CodeWordsUpC[CodeNum]:
                print(LettersUpC[CodeNum])
                break
            else:
                CodeNum = CodeNum + 1
```

Comment: Begs the question, why use `print` in the first place? By "have it be a different variable each time", are you invisioning a list of print outputs?

Comment: But it's a while loop,

Comment: I don't understand why you expect that to cause a problem. Did you read the advice in the linked duplicate? Do you know what a list is? (I hope you do, because you are already using one in your code.) Do you know how to append elements to a list?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - OP may want a list. We need to sort out what is meant by "a different variable each time" and then show how this is done with `print`. Is OP thinking of a dynamic set of named variables (then a dict may be a good solution) or something else? OP should show us in the code what variables should be set. Then tell us whether the `print` should show on the screen _and_ save to a variable.

Comment: @tdelaney If OP is thinking of multiple, dynamically named variables (and I can't really see any other possibility) then a list is the correct solution - because the source data is a list, and the natural pattern for dynamically generating the names is ascending integers, i.e., list indices. Some answers at the linked duplicate mention lists. Whether or not the `print` should also occur is a trivial adjustment to the code.

Comment: output = [":",]
InOrOut = str(input("Encode or Decode, E/D: "))
if InOrOut == "D":
    while 1 == 1:
        CodeWord = str(input("Code-word: "))
        Stop = ["Stop", "Exit", "End", "Terminate"]
        if CodeWord in Stop:
            exit("User Terminate")
        while CodeNum < 55:
            if CodeWord == CodeWordsUpC[CodeNum]:
                output.append(LettersUpC[CodeNum])
                break
            else:
                CodeNum = CodeNum + 1 """would this work?"""

Comment: @Karl Knetchel, will this work?: output = [":", ] output.append(LettersUpC[CodeNum])

Comment: Why not **try it**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a modified version that will work.

```
output = [":", ]
RTs = 0
InOrOut = str(input("Encode or Decode, E/D: "))
if InOrOut == "D":
    while RTs < 9:
        CodeNum = 0
        CodeWord = str(input("Code-word: "))
        Stop = ["Stop", "Exit", "End", "Terminate"]
        if CodeWord in Stop:
            break
        while CodeNum < 55:
            if CodeWord == CodeWordsUpC[CodeNum]:
                output.append(LettersUpC[CodeNum])
                break
            else:
                CodeNum = CodeNum + 1
        RTs = RTs + 1
    print(str(output[1] + output[2] + output[3]
              + output[4] + output[5] + output[6]
              + output[7] + output[8])) """This you might want to change to more depending on the amount of code-words you want to traselate"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new list and append values to the list and you can access it once you get out of loop by indexing or you can also try creating a dict and add key as a value you want to give it to variable name or value for that key as your output of print statement.

```
while RTs < 9:
        CodeNum = 0
        CodeWord = str(input("Code-word: "))
        Stop = ["Stop", "Exit", "End", "Terminate"]
        if CodeWord in Stop:
            break
        while CodeNum < 55:
            if CodeWord == CodeWordsUpC[CodeNum]:
                output.append(LettersUpC[CodeNum])
                break
            else:
                CodeNum = CodeNum + 1
        RTs = RTs + 1
```

Comment: this basiclly what I used to make it work But it still has some problems

Comment: Karl Knetchel helped me fix the problems! (:

Comment: @ allexiusw, the part about the dict is unclear

Comment: Create an empty dictionary   `diction={} ` and for each iteration assign the `LettersUpC[CodeNum]` to a variable you wannt it be stored like `diction['a']=LettersUpC[CodeNum]`. Once you get out of loop you can access using `diction['a']`.                                                                   Its better to use list over dictionary here , as it is confusing to assign different variable each time using dictionary